# React+Node Express, downloaded docx file is corrupted

Tags: node.js, reactjs, download, axios

I've read through alot of similiar questions, tried alot of suggested solutions, and none worked for me. So, i send the file from the backend using "res.download('directory/' + filename)", and judging from the response headers, i do get the correct file. There are no other files in the folder i'm sending from, and the original file is 14KB. However the 'data' part of the response is around 21KB. This is what i do with the response on the web app to get the file:

```
await axios.get(`api` + file.id, 
        {headers: {'x-access-token': token}}, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }
    ).then((response) => {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data])); //specifying the type here doesn't help
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute('download', `${filename}`); //filename = the name of the file i'm trying to download
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
    })
```

And the file i get in result is also around 21KB, and does not open in word due to it being corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add the file extension at the end of the filename like this:

```
 link.setAttribute('download', `${filename}.docx`);
```

Comment: File extension is already in the filename, so this does nothing. Just tested it to make sure.

Comment: @Noname Does the actual downloaded file you see have the file extension?

Comment: Yes, it does have.

Answer (score 1):

Fiddled a bit with the axios.get syntax, put the "responseType" togather with the config which has headers. And now the file i get is not corrupted o_o

```
axios.get(`api/` + file.id, 
  {
    headers: 
    {
      'x-access-token': token
    },
    responseType: 'arraybuffer' 
  }
)
```

At first i thought that the file size was different, but it's not. So that definately fixed it lol. That's what i get from being a noob in js.